# Is there an IBM iSeries command that lists all objects owned by a specific user?

Tags: ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I am trying to run DSPOBJAUT to check the ownership of every programs that needs to be checked, however this is very tedious given the long list of programs that needs to be checked. Is there another way that I can view a list of objects or programs from a specific user instead of checking every object one-by-one using DSPOBJAUT?

Answer (score 3):

WRKOBJOWN might work for you, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

IBM i services provide many system informations as SQL objects. [OBECT_OWNERSHIP](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=services-object-ownership-view) fits your need

```
select * from qsys2.OBJECT_OWNERSHIP where authorization_name = 'XXX'
```